# Nested Summation Formula Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm currently taking a discrete mathematics course, and we're learning about summation formulas. I need to create a formula for the nested summation

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^i 2^i
$$

I started with the inner summation:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{i} 2^i
$$

and arrived at

$$
2^{i+1} - 1
$$

I plugged this into the outer summation

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i+1}-1
$$

The following is my work for evaluating the outer sum:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i+1}- \sum_{i=0}^{n}1 = 2(\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^{i})- n = 2(2^{n+1} - 1) - n = 2^{n+2} - 2 - n
$$

So my final answer is $\ 2^{n+2}-2-n$. However, when I checked my answer on Wolfram Alpha, it says my answer should be $\ 2^{n+1}(n+1)$ check here [Wolfram source](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20sum%202%5Ei%20j%20%3D%200%20to%20i%20i%20%3D0%20to%20n). Can someone please explain how I am supposed to arrive at what Wolfram Alpha is saying and point out where I went wrong with my computation? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: your inner summation is not correct. Observe that the summand $2^i$ is independend of $j$. So the inner sum is $\sum_{j=0}^i 2^i = 2^i\sum_{j=0}^i1 = 2^i(i + 1)$.

Comment: @jflipp but since its executing from j to i doesn't that mean it will sum 2^i j times?

Comment: The answer from Wolframalpha is $2^{n+1} n+1=n2^{n+1}+1$, which is not the same as $2^{n+1}(n+1)=n2^{n+1}+2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Addendum**

A much neater method!

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^i 2^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)2^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n \overbrace{2i2^i-i2^i}^{i2^i}+2^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n i2^{i+1}-(i-1)2^i\\
&=n2^{n+1}-(-1)2^0&&\text{(by telescoping)}\\
&=\color{red}{n2^{n+1}+1}\end{align}$$

---

*(Original answer below)*
$$\scriptsize\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^i 2^i
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=j}^n 2^i
&&(0\le j\le i\le n)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n 2^j\cdot \frac {2^{n-j+1}-1}{2-1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n 2^{n+1}-2^j\\
&=(n+1)2^{n+1}-\frac {2^{n+1}-1}{2-1}\\
&=(n+1)2^{n+1}-2^{n+1}+1\\
&=\color{red}{n2^{n+1}+1}\end{align}$$
Alternatively,
$$\scriptsize\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^i 2^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i\sum_{j=0}^i 1\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)2^i\\
&=1(2^0)+2(2^1)+3(2^2)+4(2^3)+\cdots+(n+1)2^n\\\\
\times 2:\qquad
2S
&=\quad\qquad 1(2^1)+2(2^2)+3(2^3)+\cdots+\quad \quad n2^n+(n+1)2^{n+1}\\\\
\text{Subtracting:}\quad 
2S-S&=\;-2^0\;\;\;-2^1\quad\ -2^2\quad -2^3\ -\cdots\qquad\ \  -2^n+(n+1)2^{n+1}
\\\\
S&=-(1+2+2^2+2^3+\cdots+2^n)+(n+1)2^{n+1}\\\\
&=-\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2-1}+(n+1)2^{n+1}\\
&=\color{red}{n2^{n+1}+1}\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you like it :)

Comment: See addendum for a much shorter method!

Answer (score 0):

You did the following sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=0}^{i} 2^{\color{red}{j}} 
\end{eqnarray*}
You should have done
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{j=0}^{i} 2^{\color{red}{i}} =(i+1)2^i 
\end{eqnarray*}
The second sum then gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)2^i = n2^{n+1} +1.
\end{eqnarray*}